# While converting dataset to xml special characters are converted to hexadecimal equivalent of their ASCII value

Tags: c#, xml, dataset, ascii

```
DataSet excelAsDataset = GetExcelAsDataSet(pathToExcelFile,firstRowIsHeader);
string inputXML = excelAsDataset.GetXml();
XmlDocument returnDoc = new XmlDocument();
returnDoc.LoadXml(inputXML);
returnDoc.Save(@"C:\xmlOut.xml");
return returnDoc;
```

My Excel sheet has column attributes like `Data(12)` or `Test\nsystem` but it is displaying like

```
<NewDataSet>
  <RowItem>
    <Row>
    <Date_x0028_12_x0029__>Second</Date_x0028_12_x0029__>
    <_x003_test_x000A_system>n.a.</_x003_test_x000A_system>
    </Row>
  </RowItem>
<NewDataSet>
```

Comment: did you try `excelAsDataset.WriteXml()`?

Comment: yes i tried that and still the same problem

Comment: Well it's got to generate legal names, and this is its way of doing it. If you want something different, run an XSLT transformation on the result.

Comment: Solved the problem but it is accepting some characters like "-" or "." that is why i was curious